# QField raster GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, geopackage, qfield

I tried converting my TIFF images to a geopackage (to decrease the file size) since I would be loading my project file to QField. However, upon packaging and opening my QField geopackaged project file in my tablet, I kept on encountering this error (see attached image)

[image]

I also checked the layer satellite image gpkg layer and encountered the error:

> This layer is invalid. This might be due to a network issue, a missing file or a misconfiguration of the project

Are there any possible solutions for this?

Comment: Here's a possibility... AFAIK, Geopackages can only store 8-bit images.  If the source tif bit depth was somerhing else, say 16- or 32-bit, that might be the source of the problem?

Comment: I sometimes get that error for no reason. The project work in QField then it just stops working... Then I have to delete it and transfer it again from my computer and it works. Dont know why though,,

Comment: Hi. I downloaded the tifs from the XYZ tile (Google Satellite Image), then converted the exported tiff into geopackage.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/409004/edit) and specify how you converted your tifs to geopackage. Did you follow the method specified in the QField documentation? https://qfield.org/docs/data-formats/index.html#use-geopackage